# Can't resolve parent properties in child pom.xml

Tags: maven, jenkins, groovy, pom.xml, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to configure my sonarqube exclusions via pom.xml. The whole SonarQube configuration I have in my groovy script, but the exclusions I want to read from the pom file.

This is my **parent pom** :

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>my.company.base</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>JREV-553-20170331.090219-7</version>
    <name>parent</name>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
    <default_exclusions>**/*View*,**/*Filter*.class,**/*Builder*.class</default_exclusions>
    </properties>
```

This is my **child pom**

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>my.company.base</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>JREV-553-20170331.090219-7</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>my.app.global</groupId>
    <artifactId>application-ui</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>master-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
         <custom_exclusions>${default_exclusions},**/*WebserviceClientConfiguration*,**/*UI*</custom_exclusions> 
    </properties>
```

And I have my **Groovy script** where I am trying to read the exclusions from the child pom.xml. Here is the part of it:

```
def pom = readMavenPom file: 'pom.xml'
def PROJECT_CUSTOM_EXCLUSIONS=pom.properties.custom_exclusions
println "PROJECT_CUSTOM_EXCLUSIONS " + "$PROJECT_CUSTOM_EXCLUSIONS"
```

Can somebody explain to me why **instead of**

```
PROJECT_CUSTOM_EXCLUSIONS **/*View*,**/*Filter*.class,**/*Builder*.class, **/*WebserviceClientConfiguration*,**/*UI*
```

I **receive** :

```
PROJECT_CUSTOM_EXCLUSIONS ${default_exclusions}, **/*WebserviceClientConfiguration*,**/*UI*
```

In my effective pom.xml I receive the following

```
 <custom_exclusions>**/*View*,**/*Filter*.class,**/*Builder*.class,**/*WebserviceClientConfiguration*,**/*UI*</custom_exclusions>
```

I think I am missing something, and can't find what exactly.

Comment: My guess is that `readMavenPom` is just parsing the child POM, not actually running Maven as checking the effective POM would do. Could be wrong though. I added the jenkins-pipeline tag, maybe one of the experts will weigh in now.

Comment: `readMavenPom` will read only the pom file you have addressed nothing else and will not do inheritance nor any interpolation etc. Apart from that shouldn't those exclusions being configured in SonarQube as project configuration...